# not getting post value from tinyme in php

Tags: php, post, tinymce, wysiwyg

i am new to this tinymce editor. I have used it on my site but i am facing a little problem that is, when i add a class to the textarea my content does not update, means i do not get values by $_POST. but when i remove the editor class from the textarea i get the values and content is updated.. below is my code please help what to do  ??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/tinymce/tiny_mce.js?1"></script>
<textarea  id="wysiwyg"   name="longDescription" style="padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 250px;" placeholder="Type a description for this product here..."><?php echo $editdetails;?></textarea>
if( $_POST['update']){
$details= mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( $_POST["longDescription"] ) ) ;
//update query//
}
```

how to get the post value ?? in the $details variable ?? as i am getting value without using the  `id="wysiwyg"`

Comment: I have found out a weird problem .. that is the file name is add_products.php , now when i upload the file to server (no changes) just upload.. and edit the form, it gets edited for the first time.. when i edit it again and submit the data, it doesnt update.. then i need to upload the same file again and edit the form.. it gets updated..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

i just removed mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags()) from

mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( $_POST["longDescription"] ) ) ;